# Synchronization in java-- new ReentrantLock(true) and new ReentrantLock(false) producing the same result?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

**ReentrantLock** provides `boolean fair` flag while creating a Lock object.

1. `fair`:`true`

   Threads are given access to  critical section based on the time they have been waiting.
2. `fair`:`false`

   There is no specific policy for giving critical section to the threads.

Below is my code for the same:

```
public class ThreadDemo {
    private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock(false);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadDemo td = new ThreadDemo();
        Thread[] tArr = new Thread[5];
        // Creates 5 thread and stores them in a array
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            tArr[i] = new Thread(() -> {
                td.enterCriticalSection(new Date().getTime());
            }, "Thread " + i);
        }
        // Iterate through the array and start it.
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            tArr[i].start();
            try {
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    public void enterCriticalSection(long waitTime) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " requesting critical section at:"
                + new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:SSS").format(new Date().getTime()));
        // Gets Lock
        lock.lock();

        try {
            /*
             * Logs the entry time in critical section and waiting period for
             * the thread
             */
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " in critical section at  "
                    + new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:SSS").format(new Date().getTime()));
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // Releases lock
            lock.unlock();
        }
            
        }
}
```

But for both ***fair as true*** and ***fair as false*** i am getting the same result i.e the thread which waits for the longest period gets the critical section

```
Thread 0 requesting critical section at:01:57:48:562
Thread 0 in critical section at  01:57:48:563
Thread 1 requesting critical section at:01:57:49:520
Thread 2 requesting critical section at:01:57:50:520
Thread 3 requesting critical section at:01:57:51:520
Thread 4 requesting critical section at:01:57:52:520
Thread 1 in critical section at  01:57:53:564
Thread 2 in critical section at  01:57:58:564
Thread 3 in critical section at  01:58:03:565
Thread 4 in critical section at  01:58:08:566
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `fair false` means is that the lock will let threads in however it wants.  With a small number of threads, it might just happen to be the order they've been waiting, but it doesn't make any guarantees of this.

Comment: I tried with 10-20 threads at first and tried it multiple numbers of times, even i thought that it would assigning the lock based on the order of request for the critical section

Comment: @DharmvirTiwari  The javadoc says that `ReentrantLock(true)` must create a fair lock, but it does _not_ say that `ReentrantLock(false)` must create an _unfair_ lock.  If your JRE appears to create a fair lock even when `fair==false`, then that does not prove that there's anything wrong with it.